# CPU Fan Error during boot

Tags: cpu, cpu-cooler

I have recently built a new pc with the following specs:

```
Intel i7 2600k 3.4Ghz
16GB memory
Asus Sabertooth P67 motherboard
Zotac GeForce GTX 550Ti graphix card
OCZ Agility 3 128GB SSD
2TB 7200 RPM Segate HD
Windows 7 64-bit
```

I have successfully overclocked the cpu to 4.7Ghz.  The issue is that when I start the computer from a cold boot (where the computer is turned off for more than 2 hours), I get a CPU fan error when the pc is first booting up (before windows loads up).  The fan is working.  Then if I reboot the pc any number of times, I will not get the error.  It only happens on the initial boot.

Any ideas how I can resolve it?  Is there a issue with the motherboard?

Comment: Check the BIOS settings for the fan monitoring. Most likely, it's set too high and the fan isn't quite spinning that fast when the BIOS checks it. Did you 100% confirm that the CPU isn't throttling under load? (If it's throttling, the overclock was *not* successful and will make the computer slower!)

Comment: I left the fan settings to default which is 600 rpm.  I looked at the specs for the fan & the RPM for the fan is between 600 & 2000.  I bios complains only when the rpm goes under 600.  Sorry for the n00b question but how would I know if the CPU is throttling?